# Running with clothes

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I have created a character with multiple layers of clothing and am trying to make her run with the cloths responding realistically. My issue is that every time she runs, using cloth physics, her cloths all ride up to her midriff. I have weight painted the upper clothing to make them stay still, but can't make the lower work properly. I have maximized the steps and played with the settings to no avail...
I don't know how to put the character up for people to look at... any help would be very appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Pinning may be your answer.  Go into EDIT MODE and select some vertecies where you want the cloth to remain, [CTL][G] to group them and under your Cloth Simulation settings in the Physics Tab, select Pinning and the group which you formed.  This will at least keep the spots pinned to the locations where you want them to remain while allowing the remainder of the simulation to flow as normal.  I've used this before and it may require a little playing to get the pinning correct to keep from some weird artifacts forming in the sim, but it should be helpful for you.  If you have to, you may need to add a HOOK to the vertecies you have pinned and parent the hook to your mesh (I don't recall if pinning stays in one selection of 3D space or moved with the animation, therefore the possible use of the hook)